# Xamarin IOS BackGgroundColor doesn't work?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, background-color, stacklayout

I have a problem with the header of a listview, as I understand it, unlike Android, on IOS by default I have the background color = White .. I would like to have it as transparent as on android in fact, but I can't set it up, I'll post the code:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB4tZ.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not post code as images

Comment: Please provide the code as text using code formatting. Could you also please elaborate on the problem you are facing? What have you tried already?

Comment: By the way, you can use the "Transparent" moniker for  the color transparent instead of using `#00ffffff`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to this [Cell Background Color on iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/cell-background-color).

In your code, change

```
<ViewCell Height="25" x:Name="ViewCellWithe" >
```

to

```
ViewCell Height="25" x:Name="ViewCellWithe" ios:Cell.DefaultBackgroundColor="Transparent" >
```

Comment: Thx, this document is helpful.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Could my answer help you?